# Will these low watt LEDs work with a 12V transformer?

Tags: lighting, led

I've inherited a pretty poor quality garden light kit that runs off a 12V/2500mA AC transformer. It supports x6 lanterns which each have a measly 5W halogen bulb. Barely illuminating anything.

If I swap the bulbs out for LEDs I figure I can have a 200Lm or more while easily staying under the maximum 30W load on the transformer.

My question is will they work and what exact specification would I need? I've seen various models some consuming between 1.2W to 2W. Is there any danger this is too low? Are all G4 capsules designed to run off low voltage AC transformers designed for halogen bulbs?

Comment: Thanks both. I was confused between those two links with the same main product description and meant to post 12V version. Also 10W vs 20W (equivalent wattage) both listed as 200Lm. Another mistake?

Comment: The comparison tool link is dynamic (session-based) and isn't persistent. I've reverted it to the 12v product link. At any rate, we're in the realm of product recommendations, which is off-topic.

Comment: That's annoying. It offered me that URI in the "share link" function. I was interested in discussing technical specs rather than product recommendations. I will reword my question

Comment: i don't see which ones you ask specifically about, but generally that's fine. the risk would actually be placing too low a load on an unregulated transformer, which causes it to spit out more than 12v, which the retrofit LEDs may or may not mind. a multimeter removes doubt, but you don't want to fed the LEDs more than ~16v. You can get a 12v DC adapter at salvation army/goodwill for a couple bucks if needed.

Comment: Thanks Dan. I removed the product links as that was verging "off topic". I discovered for myself that I should have DC output, but neglected originally to mention that my transformer was AC. I've since bought a 12v DC adapter replacement and some apparently compatible LEDs and will see how it goes. Feel free to add an answer regarding DC and I'll accept it.